# Calling parent class in python

Tags: python, class, oop

My issue here is with calling classes inside another class. Independently, I can set this up how I want the 2 classes to work. I just cannot get them working together. I want my dataset (which is football fixtures and results) to be passed to a class League, which holds all the league info and then every team inside that league is inside the class Team which is a child of the parent class League. Example shows just a snippet of how this is set up

At the bottom of the example you will see the function 'total_attack_strength_home(self):' Here I need to access the class Team, but then the last part of the calculation references the respective class object (The league that the club sits in). Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks

'''

```
class League(): 
    def init(self,league): 
        self.league = league 
        self.total_goals_scored = self.get_total_goals_scored() 
        self.home_goals_scored = self.get_home_goals_scored()
    def get_total_goals_scored(self):
        pass
    def get_home_goals_scored(self):
        pass


class Team(League): 
    def init(self,club): 
    self.club = club 
    self.home_wins = self.get_home_wins() 
    self.home_draws = self.get_home_draws()

    def total_attack_strength(self):
        if len(self.total_goals) == 0:
            attack_strength = 0
        else:
            attack_strength = (sum(self.total_goals) / len(self.total_goals)) / ***(total_goals_scored/games_played)***
        return attack_strength'''
```

Comment: I'm not much of an OOP guy, but it seems totally wrong here for `Team` to be a subclass of `League`. A Team is not itself also a League. You probably want to use "composition" here rather than inheritance.

Comment: I'm fairly to new to it too, hence the question. I'll look into that, thanks for the comment

Comment: Check out the `super()` function. There's a lot to read, too much to explain here. Also, your `init()` function should use `super()` to invoke the baseclass' `init()`.

Comment: Thank you Ulrich

Comment: `super` is irrelevant, because `Team` should not be inheriting from `League` at all. A league is a *collection* of teams.  Both methods in `League` should be defined in `Team`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few variables that don’t seem to be defined anywhere, so I’m assuming this Is just a snippet example.

As mentioned, use `super` when you want parent class code to run. So in the child’s `init`, throw a `super().__init__()` to get the parent’s `init` running. If you’re just trying to access the parents attributes, remember you inherited those. So a `self.foo` will get either your or your parents definition of `foo` automatically, whichever happened last (which will be the child’s in most cases).

Answer (score 0):

I think your class League should be abstract (delegating the implementation to the subclasses).

Like:

```
import abc
class League(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    ....

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_total_goals_scored(self):
        pass
```

Then you'll need to implement it on your Team class.

In addition to what's already commented (considering using composition rather than inheritance) and missing to invoke the parent constructor on your child class